# How to make a dynamic picklist field as required in vf?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I am creating a popup which shows some product details along with dynamic contact list.how to make this dynamic picklist as required or through an error when if its not selected or the value is "--select--" when clicking on button?
 my code is in image[image]

Comment: please use [edit] to indicate current state of code - don't paste pictures, see [ask] for formatting tips

Answer (score 0):

In apex controller side. You can write custom messages .

Assume,
suppose you are validating picklist part while submitting the record

```
if(string.isBlank(selectedConId)){
  ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please select 
a value'));
     return null;
}
```

Use  following tag in vf page:

```
    < apex:Pagemessages/>
```

Comment: ,Thanks for reply. I tried with this and it showed error void(isblank) stirng type doesn't exist. i added string.isblank() but still its executing when clicking on button and showing error in debug log.

Comment: Just check seleccondid==null || seleccondid==''.. it may work

Comment: 1) `String.isBlank(selectedConId)` is preferred construction and 2) need to remove `required=` on `selectList` - otherwise controller will never be invoked

Comment: @cropredy still it's not working.

Comment: @annappa PH Stiil facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you in the question, there will be always a default value in selectList i.e. "--select--" will be always selected, hence make below changes to your code

1. In addition to checking null or blank value, also check if the value
   is not equal to "--select--" in your controller and throw the error
   back.
2. Remove required = true from selectList as there will be always a
   default value of "--select--" in your selectList.